# How could I make my perl script add a server's key to SSH's list?

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a very annoying problem that has left me scratching me head when my script does not work.

My script need to SSH into my VMware box to run some commands, well I had moved my work from one computer to another (Both running Ubuntu 10.10). And when I ran my script it failed gloriously. I looked through and found that nothing was wrong... and worked on the other machine which was sitting next to me. I had found the problem to be the SSH client, the box I had moved my work to had never logged into the VMware server before so it did have the SSH key for that server stored. Once I ran SSH on its own the script worked fine from then on.

Which brings me to my question.

In perl is there some way I can allow my script to add a SSH key to machine that has never been connected to before? Instead of having to run SSH and answer "yes" to the question it presents me with asking if I want to permanently add the servers key to my SSH file(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script can run ssh with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to automatically accept host keys from unknown hosts. This has security implications, and I believe even with this option ssh will refuse to connect if the host is already known and the key changes, although that's not clear to me from the documentation.

Comment: Well that is more information than I had before. I am using a perl module called Net::OpenSSH, I might need to switch it out to make my script accept this idea. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Solignis: read the module FAQ included inside its documentation (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::OpenSSH#FAQ)

Comment: I read through it last night and saw something that caught my eye, I will read in more depth.

Comment: How do I enable that option? Is that the SSH binary in Linux or an option of Net::OpenSSH?